# How to: Icon/Image constantly appear over scroll-sections like in twitter?

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, twitter

So I would like to have an button or vector-icon simular to twitters one like in this image: [twitter button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlk2O.jpg)

So the concept is like in this picture: [concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgseO.png)

The black rectangles represent the scrollable sections which is basicalle a scrollview. Now I would like to make an icon/picture appear over all these sections constantly like in twitter. In my second picture that would be the blue star. I havent found simmlular concepts yet. How can I implement that in React Native?

Comment: You want to attach icon/picture to every section or just want one icon/picture for all the sections

Comment: @AwaisRana one picture that stays constantly in the right bottom corner and over every section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { View, ScrollView } from 'react-native'

export default class Example extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <ScrollView>
                    {/* Children */}
                </ScrollView>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.6}
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 60
                    }}
                    // onPress={this.onAddPress}
                >
                    {/* Provide icon source here */}
                    <Image source={iconSource} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

If you need this bottom picture to be on every screen, then you can place this `TouchableOpacity` component to all of those screen but outside of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. But now the image that I import is way too big. I tried to use width and heigth but it will not get smaller. Its like all over the screen. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can set height and width to the image and set the `resizeMode={'contain'}` to the image something like:

`<Image source={imageSource} style={{ height: 40, width: 40 }} resizeMode={'contain'} />`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Fab button available in native-base and react-native-paper

[native-base] https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#fabs-def-headref

[reac-native-paper] https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/fab.html

If you want non-touchable custom fab then use can use given code

```
<View style={{position:'absolute', zIndex:99, bottom:15, right:15}}>
  <FontAwesome name="star" color={"blue"} size={25} />
</View>
```

If you want touchable custom fab then use can use given code

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>/*submit code*/} style={{position:'absolute', zIndex:99, bottom:15, right:15}}>
  <FontAwesome name="star" color={"blue"} size={25} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```